# Spring MVC vs ASP.NET (MVC?)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, spring, spring-mvc, content-management-system

I have to work to develop a management from a clothing company. 
Is more appropriate to choose asp.net or spring? 
What are the reasons for the choice? What are the advantages of Spring MVC over fact-based ASP.net and vice versa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maturity wise, ASP.NET MVC and Spring MVC is mature MVC framework and relatively the same. Like Daniele said, one thing you have to consider now is the learning curve. If your background is Java then it is probably best to choose Spring MVC and if your background is .NET then it is wise to choose ASP.NET MVC.

Out of the box, ASP.NET MVC just works. You do not need to plug in many different technologies to work with ASP.NET MVC. It is a bit different story with Spring MVC. You need to plug-in other frameworks like Hibernate/JPA/iBatis for persistence, JSP/Velocity/Freemarker for templating, etc.

Another thing you have to consider is the money your customer is willing to invest to get this system running. Running an ASP.NET MVC app is relatively more expensive than running a Spring MVC app.

Other than everything that has been mentioned, is your customer a large enterprise? If not, other MVC frameworks based on PHP or Ruby on Rails would probably be sufficient for your customer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I donot think we need Hibernate, Velocity and freemarker for coding with Spring they have very specific use just make use of existing Spring APIs to develop a good maintainable web solution. I have worked both with .Net and Spring framework and i tell you Spring is the best because you have total control on everything you code, maintenance is easier and the coolest of all it has IOC and i like it to the depth of my heart it feels like magic working with IOC.

Comment: By now dotnet core MVC also has IOC and is completely plugable, open source and runs on Linux. So I think they are on even ground now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Spring.Net very well, but i think the advantage of ASP.NET MVC is on the diffusion, you can find a lot of documentation and a vaste community that works with it at enterprise level web applications.

I think that the possible advantages of Spring relies on the framework, that have a lot of "sub frameworks" inside it, AOP, his own IoC container and more cool stuff.

I think also, learning curve with ASP.NET MVC is much easier.

Comment: by `Spring.Net` you mean `Spring MVC`?

Comment: I mean [Spring.NET](http://springframework.net/)

Comment: OP's question is about "`Spring MVC` (not `Spring.Net`) vs `ASP.NET MVC`" - so not sure why you mentioned that you're not familiar with `Spring.Net` before discussing `ASP.NET MVC`